# CreateDir sometimes take a few second (in other pc directory)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I just tried to create directory in other PC (Network PC) using `CreateDir` function.

```
uses DateUtils;

var StartDate,EndDate:TDatetime
begin
  StartDate:=Now;
  if CreateDir([NetworkPC_Folder]) then
  begin
    EndDate:=Now;
    Showmessage(
      'Succesfull !'+sLineBreak+
      'It takes '+IntToStr(MilliSecondsBetween(StartDate,EndDate))+' ms ');
  end else
  begin
    EndDate:=Now;
    Showmessage(
      'Failed !'+sLineBreak+
      'Error Code is '+IntToStr(GetLastError)+sLineBreak+
      'It takes '+IntToStr(MilliSecondsBetween(StartDate,EndDate))+' ms '); 
  end;
end;
```

First try was working 
- return value is True, successful created
- work fast (but sometimes takes a long time too)

Second try was working 
- return value is False because directory already exists
- work fast

In an X try was working 
- but takes a few second to give a result value

I just curios why sometimes it takes a little bit longer.

Is other function in Delphi7 to check directory (and create it if it doesn't exists) faster than `CreateDir` to check/create folder in Network PC?

**Note:**
- `CreateDir` in Local PC is always fast
- fast means it takes 0 seconds
- a little bit longer means it takes 1-7 seconds

Comment: Delphi is not relevant. It's a winapi question.

Comment: Run Wireshark/Message Analyzer/Netmon *(pick your choice)* when executing your code and look at response times when it's *slow*. More than likely, it's network related.

Comment: CreateDir uses the CreateDirectory Windows API and from what I can see on the web; It may experience latency on network paths. One person noted that developers creating network intensive apps on other OSes struggle when they port that app to Windows. I would at the very least eliminate the possibility of an unresponsive network first before proceeding with the coding side. Test the bits out of it just to make sure.

Comment: OK, so I can't make it fast all the time then, because it's just about network response time

Comment: You have to be certain it is not just the network causing the issue. If you eliminated the network as the cause (including your computer and maybe software on it) then I would assume that it is the way that Windows does it that causes the issue.

Comment: @FZS Realistically, all your code does is ask the OS to do the job for you. What optimisation could you expect to apply to your code?

Comment: "I just curios" - On a Windows network, these delays are typically due to DNS resolution of the destination machine and verifying authentication/access permissions.

Comment: @MartynA. I don't think DNS is to blame here. I reckon authentication might play a role but I think the way Microsoft has done networking since forever plays an even bigger role. MS is not keen on changing underlying technologies that often. They like creating bright and shiny new things that they can sell, but fixing a poor performer will most probably never happen. Just my 2 cents. Anyway I am off-topic.

Comment: Just for information, a few days ago I tried to load image from my PC (WinXP) using TImage from image in network PC (Win7), sometimes fast sometimes take a few seconds to load.  
Then tried from Win7 to Win7 and the image loading always fast.